# allowLargeResults in Query job in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a Query job in BigQuery and getting the following error:

> Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to
>   true in your job configuration

I understand that I need to set **allowLargeResults** to **True** in my job configuration, but then I also have to supply a destination table field.

I don't want to insert the results of the query to specific table, only to process it locally. 
how can I manage this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to insert the results of the query to specific table,
>   only to process it locally.

Wanted to clarify – so you hopefully feel better about using destination table:
In reality, any query result ends up in some table!
If result is smaller than 128MB - BigQuery creates temporary table on your behalf (in special dataset which name starts with underscore so it is not visible in Web UI dataset/table navigator).
This temporary table is available for 24 hours and is used if you use Query Cashing or you can even use it by yourself – you just need to find which table is created. You can find this in API – destination table – which as I said above exists even if you have not set specific table. Or you can find it in Web UI

[image]

[image]
When result is bigger than 128MB – you must set destination table. The only drawback in your case is that you need to make sure you delete this table after you don’t need it anymore otherwise you will be paying for storage

You can do this either by actually deleting table - manually (in UI) or programmatically (API). Or you can set expiration on the table (API)

Answer (score 3):

First of all if it's means it's too large, then probably greater than 128MB. You need to make sure that you query is accurate and if indeed you want to return the large data. Usually people make mistakes in the queries, like join explosion, missing time filters to reduce data, or missing limits.

After you are convinced the data is too large, you need to write to a table, then export to GCS, then download, and then deal with it.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exportingmultiple